# What do space barbarians do to pass the time?

Tags: internal-consistency

Imagine you are a raging, lobotomised and artificially enhanced humanoid (maybe you were human once, but your certainly not anymore) and you've gone on a glorious journey to this little blue planet called "Earth" (other blue planets are available) to rape, burn, murder and pillage your merry way around the planet and return home to your Overlady who rules you with an iron fist (she literally has an iron fist, loss of limbs is quite common).

Then imaging that something bad happens in hypersleep (or to the FTL drive, or in the "warp" etc. etc.) and all of those nice broodmothers that give you your sleepy drugs and keep you docile on long journeys (and short journeys, and while going to the toilet, and while you are consuming your nourishment etc.) are killed leaving just you and your equally deranged brothers-in-arms to crash land on the little blue planet, with no way of returning home.

And then imagine (this deal keeps getting worse all the time!) that the prosperous society you were heading to make such good friends with has actually managed to mysteriously extinct itself (and all other life) before you got there, so there is nothing there for you to do your usual hobbies, of inflicting pain and bloody death, with or to. Sure the radiation count is a little higher than it was expected to be, but that just improves your tan.

What is a "person" so used to killing and fighting going to do with their time? They do not fear death, hunger, pain, cold, boredom etc. that would drive a normal human being to search for supplies or build a settlement until help arrives. ANd they are too loyal to turn on each other for fun or food.

Would/could they work out how to do anything for themselves? One step at a time like a baby learning to walk. Or would they die of dehydration a few days later, angrily chewing off their own lips in search of moisture after spending the last few days running and kicking bits of rubble in an attempt to inflict pain upon them?

I know this question may be considered opinion based, so I am making it clear that I am looking **only for answers that have some sort of basis in science or psychology** and so would be feasible in our reality.

Comment: These are not Barbarians, they are the Daleks. *Exterminate....Exterminate....*

Comment: Except my boys can climb stairs unaided!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as a barbarian horde member you are probably raiding not just to fulfill your bloodlust, but also to raid for valuable supplies and items.  Likely they would be trained in reconnaissance in identifying valuable targets to acquire and scouting enemy military locations.

Given all of the above, they would most likely spend their time looking for survivors (to kill) or hidden supply caches (to raid).  Think laser digging into underground bunkers type of action.

Depending on the level of their conditioning (totally unthinking berserkers) and their reliance on guidance from superiors that no longer exist, they might continue their search for something to raid or kill until they starve, dehydrate or irradiate themselves to death.

Comment: I like the "search and destroy" programming over my original idea of "destroy, destroy, DESTROY!". I hadn't considered that just because I know everyone on the blue planet is crispy toast, it doesn't mean these guys do, so they would be out searching high and low for their next target/victim. Though they may not find any people they could find other interesting things that may make it worth keeping them alive.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much science or psychology for this, but how about a little history.  The Norse legends are filled with contests!  The gods themselves constantly challenge each other to eating contests, drinking contests and other tests of variant strength.

I would say that, despite their loyalty, your vikings would challenge each other to friendly fights, which given their blood savagery and their lobotomies, would likely result in more than a few deaths.

In the end, there would be only one, sad, lonely, lipless warrior, slowly dying from the thirst and radiation.

Comment: I do like the idea of competitive infighting, as it would breed strength in to the barbarians through a sort of natural selection. Unfortunately it was something I wished to avoid in their programming as it means it could happen at any time! Also dead barbarians don't fight very well (regardless of how tough they were!) so this wouldn't be particularly useful from a military or financial viewpoint. Artificially enhanced super barbarians require substancial investment and don't grow on trees! (though that is a good idea!) I do appreciate the story of the "last lipless warrior of earth". Kudos!